# onLongClickListener never get trigered

Tags: android, listview, onlongclicklistener

I have a custom listView defined like this

```
public class DDListView extends ListView implements OnScrollChangedListener {
```

than I make an instance of it with name mExampleList I set onLongClickListener but it never get called, where is my problem ?

```
mExampleList.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("vvv", "sdfsdf");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want to be using [OnItemLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) instead of `OnClickListener`.

Comment: It's the same OnLongItemClickListener

Comment: there is no OnLongItemClickListener

Comment: @Selvin http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html

Comment: 1. List view has only ListView.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener l)! 2. ListView dont have method called setOnLongItemClickListener 3. Simplest way/hack to add LongItemCLick is registerForContextMenu ! **EDIT:** in your link you point to AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener ... question: does ListView implements it ?

Comment: @Selvin Yes, it really does. Look at the documentation. I have an app that uses OnItemLongClickListener. Twice. And, I think the easiest way to use an OnItemClickListener is to use an OnItemClickListener.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA damn ... you're right ... i was thinking that setOnItemLongClickListener is hidden coz "intellisense" from Eclipse didn't show this method for me

Comment: Upvoted. :) The answer is really useful - it solved a problem for me when using Gallery in connection with a custom (compound) widget.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmm , are you trying to make all ListView longclckeable?

Some tips:

-Try first to see if normal OnClick gets fired;

-Try to see if you have setClickeable(true); on it;

-Try to see if you are really trying to do that and not an usual onItemClick() of the items in the list (to do this @override the function :
`public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {}`